# How to use a meta-analysis to assess the equivalence of two different procedures?

Tags: meta-analysis, equivalence, non-inferiority

I'm making a comparison of two surgical procedures, and I want to know how I can analyze the data I have for a meta-analysis. The overall surgical procedure is the same, but some authors choose to  modify the procedure a bit. So basically I have a large number of studies with the standard procedure and a smaller number with a modified procedure.

The outcome is percent complications, e.g., 20% of the study population had mild complications and 10% had severe complications.

What would be the best way to show if the modified procedure is as good as the standard procedure?

Comment: It's not clear from your description what the study designs are (e.g. RCTs, controlled clinical trials, single arm observational trials, etc.). That's going to be the key to determining how to meta-analyze them and whether or not you will need advanced techniques like meta-regression or not.

Comment: The question fails to indicate the effect-size. Moreover testing the difference between two procedures does not require a meta-analysis. t-test for a difference between proportions (separately for mild severe complications) could meet the end-goal.